# Strange issue combining IF and CASE in TSQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, case

Here is an issue that seems like it should be a simple solve but I have been working on it some time and cannot figure out why I cannot seem to combine CASE in one area of the query and IF in another.

Does anyone see what is going on here? I have an old data set that needs to be converted to work with new tables. The data is pulled from WDDX and put in a temp table. That's all working properly.

Here is where I am running into trouble. I need to extract a value to a new column called DetailValue when XXXX appears, and in such cases, the value appearing after XXXX is a number that belongs to DetailValue, then it is followed by _, and in such case, the number appearing after _ belongs in RiskValue.. Also, when ZZZZ appears, the following character belongs in DetailValue and it is always the last character.

When it's simply CASE, everything works fine, but when I add IF to grab a value, it tells me:

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure OldSysDataConv Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Code is:

```
 SELECT VarName, 
 CASE 
   WHEN (CHARINDEX('XXXX', VarName) > 0 and SUBSTRING(VarName, CHARINDEX('XXXX', VarName), len(VarName)) like '%XXXX%') or SUBSTRING(VarName, CHARINDEX('ZZZZ', VarName), len(VarName)) like '%ZZZZ%' then

    left(replace(left(replace(VarName, 'XXXX', ''), len(VarName)-4), 'ZZZZ', ''), (len(VarName)-5))
else
    null
END as DetailName,
IF CHARINDEX('ZZZZ', VarName) > 0 THEN
    right(VarName, 1)
END
 as DetailValue,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem by simplifying my CASE statement. Some basic logic had simply slipped by me during a long day. ;)

Answer:

```
 CASE
 WHEN CHARINDEX('XXXX', VarName) > 0 AND CHARINDEX('ZZZZ', VarName) <> 0 THEN
    substring(VarName, (CHARINDEX('_', VarName)-1), len(VarName))
 ELSE
     right(VarName, 1)
 END
 as DetailValue,
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `IF ... THEN ... END` *expression* in pure SQL. This is a procedural *statement* that is used in stored procedure.

You want either `IIF()`, which is T-SQL specific:

```
IIF(CHARINDEX('ZZZZ', VarName) > 0, right(VarName, 1), null) as DetailValue
```

Or the more standard `CASE` :

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('ZZZZ', VarName) > 0 THEN right(VarName, 1) END as DetailValue
```

Comment: How do I factor in these multiple conditions in CASE? I am not aware of a way. I'd like to be able to put IIF under CASE ELSE. I do need to combine these. If I do not, then SQL Server decides to create separate columns in my resultset.